# Displaying an String ( arraylist ) in android

Tags: android, listview, rss

I created an RSS reader and was successful in parsing data from the XML file. I have extracted the headings and I wish to display those headings. I stored the headings into an String array and i wish to display all the heading ( i have like 70 headings )  in a suitable manner. i was thinking of using Listview . Is there any other simpler way?

Comment: ListView would be a good way of displaying several headings. It is designed to handle those kinds of tasks.. If you have a way to combine some of that data into categories.. an ExpandableListView might be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` is exactly designed for this.  I would create a custom `ArrayAdapter` to be the adapter for your `ListView`.  You just need to override the `add()`, `getCount()`, and `getView()` methods to have something up and running.  Then you can store your list of XML data directly within the adapter and easily add to it.

This is a pretty good tutorial: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Only change I would make is to make data[] a `List` instead and add the `add()` and `getCount()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Custom `ArrayAdapter`, as Atlos suggests, is IMHO an overkill. Use a stock one, `ArrayAdapter<String>` over a String array. For the item template ID, there are ready made templates in Android; I'd recommend `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.